# how to make two text widgets the same size even they have different text and different fontsize

Tags: flutter

flutter how to make two text widgets the same size even they have different text and different fontsize

I have tried FittedBox but not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you want them to have the same height, right?
In that case you can use `IntrinsicHeight`. This will will force its children to have the same height (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

FittedBox is only if you want to contain a widget inside another widget. I suggest watching on YT: 'FittedBox (Flutter Widget of the Week)'

Here is a simple Code example with `IntrinsicHeight`:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text(
              'Short but big text',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 16),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              'Longer smaller text with many words',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```